# Update column with data from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, update

I am working on complicated problem, but I will simplify it to this problem.

I have two tables

```
A [ID, column1, column2, column3]
B [ID, column1, column2, column3, column4]
```

and I want to update the third:

```
C [ID, column1, column2,column3]
```

I am updating another third table using this query.

```
UPDATE C 
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secondTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  from (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, 
              (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
        from A, B limit 1; ) as t ;
```

I got:

```
UPDATE 0
```

When I run this query:

```
select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
            from A, B limit 1;
```

I got results. Am I missing something ?

Sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4d08/5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The proper form would be (assuming current pg version 9.3 for lack of information):

```
UPDATE C 
SET    column1 = A.column1 
     , column2 = B.column2 
     , column3 = A.column1 + B.column2
FROM   A
JOIN   B ON A.id = B.id  -- ??? not specified in question!
WHERE  C.id = A.id      --  ??? not specified in question!
AND   (C.column1, C.column2, C.column3) IS DISTINCT FROM
      (A.column1, B.column2, A.column1 + B.column2);
```

The last `WHERE` clause is optional to avoid empty updates that would not change anything (but still write a new row version at full cost).

[ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) already gave a basic explanation in his comment (now removed):

> You don't get duplication. Your derived table is cross joining `A` and `B` (i.e. **without any joining condition**) and then choosing an arbitrary row (`LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY`). It then uses the values from that arbitrary row to update all rows of table `C`. If you want different values to be used for different rows of C, you'll have to join the 3 tables (using `JOIN - ON` and `WHERE`)

[Refer to the manual on `UPDATE` for details.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like this:

```
UPDATE C 
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secondTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  from (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, 
              (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
        from A
        join B  on ...
        where ... ) as t
```