# Update all columns from another table

Tags: postgresql, update

I need to update a table from another one, and I need to update all columns. Besides listing every column in the `SET` clause, is there a way to update them all at once? Like this:

```
update tableA
set * = tableB.*
from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id
```

I tried in psql, it doesn't work. I have to list every column like this:

```
update tableA
set c1 = tableB.c1, c2 = tableB.c2, ...
from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id
```

`tableB` is created use `create .. like tableA`. So they are basically identical. And the reason I'm doing it is that I need to load .csv data to a temp table `tableB` and then update `tableA` based on the new data in `tableB`. `tableA` needs to be locked as little as possible and `tableA` needs to keep integrity. I'm not sure 'delete then insert' would be a good option?

Comment: I tested with your second code, it work !  You should review two topics: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58371/sql-update-column-with-data-from-another-table/58383#58383 ,  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59458/update-table-with-another-table-data/59534#59534

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is *no* syntax variant that lets you update the whole row at once. However, there is a shorter form than what you have so far.

Also, you do not actually want to update all columns. The `WHERE` condition on `id` pins down at least that column to remain unchanged. But that's just nitpicking.

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET    (  c1,   c2, ...)
     = (b.c1, b.c2, ...)
FROM   table_b b
WHERE  a.id = b.id;
```

More in this related answer:

- [Bulk update of all columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45642/bulk-update-of-all-columns/63883#63883)

#### `DELETE / INSERT`

Internally, due to the [MVCC model of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html), every `UPDATE` effectively inserts a new row anyway and marks the old one as obsolete. So, behind the curtains `UPDATE` and `DELETE` + `INSERT` are similar. There are *some* details in favor of the `UPDATE` route, though:

- [H.O.T. `UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806058/redundant-data-in-update-statements/7806610#7806610)
- [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) tables:  If you have large columns, the content may be stored "out-of-line" in TOAST tables. A new row version can carry over the same link to the same row in the TOAST table **if** that toasted field  remain unchanged.
- Index maintenance may be cheaper for updates.

Locking overhead is about the same. You need an exclusive lock on affected (existing) rows either way. So keep the transaction brief.

Different triggers are fired (if any). That may or may not be ok.

If you are dealing with a huge number of rows and you don't need a consistent outcome (all rows or none), you can split the operation into multiple batches - in separate transactions. Increases the total cost, but keeps the lock time per row shorter.

Comment: `DELETE / INSERT` may also have unwanted or just different (cascade or triggered) effects than the `UPDATE`.

Comment: It is correct but you should update alias part of table_a. table_a (which is updated table) cannot get an alias.