# Append new columns to an existing (empty) table from another table

Tags: postgresql

## Context

I have a PostgreSQL database structure with a `table1` defined with many project specific fields (which are empty now, but which will get written through an application):

[image: table1]

I have another table, let's say `table3`, already populated with (many) records of base data:

[image: table3]

I'd like to append, in a column-wise manner, all the columns from `table3` into `table1`.
These columns do not exists yet in `table1`.

The desired results would by as follows:

[image: table3 columns appended into table1]

## Question

How to achieve this in a nice way?

### What I've tried so far

I have tried to follow [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63871/update-all-columns-from-another-table), but without success because the columns defined in `table3` do not exist in `table1`:

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET (fid, attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, ...)
    =
    (b.fid, b.attrib1, b.attrib2, b.attrib3, ...)
FROM   table3 b
;

I also tried using an `INSERT` statement:
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT fid, attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, ...
FROM table3;
```

But here I face this (obvious error):

`ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns`

The third way I was thinking about was to `ALTER table1` and add all new columns, one by one, which would be tedious because of the datatype definition (which I don't want to care about because it's already defined in `table3`). There is probably a smarter way of doing that.

Comment: *The desired results would by as follows:* Do you want to obtain the rowset with shown structure and data, or you really want to alter the structure of Table1 and add more columns with the data into it?

Comment: Does `table1.id` and `table3.fid` are primary/unique? Does some value for these fields may exist in one of tables and not exist in another? if true - what result do you need for such value?

Comment: Yes, `id` and `fid` used to be serial (pkey) but `table1` is empty now, so `id` would be generated automatically(?). And the new `table1.fid` column can simply be an integer for the moment. Yes, I'd like `table1` to be updated with the column-wise structure from `table3` and their respective data. All original `table1` columns will be updated after the desired concatenate operation occurred, but I will probably have to refresh `table1` when `table3` gets updated in the future. I don't know yet.

Comment: What you want to do is contrary to data normalization. I don't see a suitable way to implement this - especially when you need to update the data from new version of `table3` content...

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Or even better as a little [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12)